# Proof of residence for Japan Airpass

Tags: air-travel, japan, star-alliance, residency, ana

To use an ANA Star Alliance Airpass, I need to provide proof that I reside outside of Japan. What would constitute acceptable proof?

Context: I'm an American living and working in the UK, and I'm planning a vacation trip to Japan. I want to buy an Airpass for domestic flights within Japan.

My local travel agent can sell me an Airpass, but says that I'll have to provide the proof of foreign residence upon check-in in Japan. Sadly, neither they nor [ANA's airpass webpage](http://www.ana.co.jp/wws/us/e/wws_common/fare/special/airpass.html) can say what would constitute proof of residence. Would a utility bill suffice? Or the UK work visa in my American passport?

Comment: BTW, I discovered that ANA introduced a new kind of air pass called the Experience Japan Fare (http://www.ana.co.jp/wws/us/e/wws_common/promotion/experience_jp/). Similar to the Airpass, it's 10500 yen per leg, except without the restriction that you have to enter Japan on a Star Alliance airline, and you can purchase it online, which effectively makes it much cheaper than buying an Airpass (through a travel agent). Same proof of foreign residence: a foreign passport, or a Japanese passport with a foreign residency visa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you continue reading the [same page](http://www.ana.co.jp/wws/us/e/wws_common/fare/special/airpass.html) you will be able to find the required information:

> Reservation, Ticketing and Check-in
>
> - Reservations must be confirmed for the first domestic sector. The dates of the remaining sectors may be left open and booked at any time before the departure of each domestic sector.
> - Reservations may be accepted no more than 355 days before the departure date of each domestic sector.
> - Payment and ticketing must be completed within 72 hours after making reservation.
> - **Upon request the passenger shall present proof of residence such as a passport/immigration stamp/visa. Additionally the international ticket must be presented at Check-in for domestic flights.**
> - Ticketing must be completed before departure for Japan.
> - Ticket must be issued on Star Alliance carriers' ticket stock (including BSP / ARC tickets)
> - Please contact one of the Star Alliance member airline reservation centers or your travel agent for reservation and purchasing tickets.
>
> (These fares are not able to buy on the ANA SKY WEB.)
>
> The ticketing service charge may be applied by the country which is reserved and bought.

So a US passport will work.

Comment: Aha; I had given up after not finding my answer under the page's "Eligibility" section. Thanks for the catch.